# Swift forward selector to multiple objects

Tags: swift, performselector

In my project I'm trying to forward protocol methods to registered elements using a mediator.

Normally in Objective-C I would ask an element if it responds to a selector and use the performSelector method. In Swift this method isn't available anymore.

So basically, this is what I want to achieve:

```
override func forwardingTargetForSelector(aSelector: Selector) -> AnyObject? {
    for element in elements {
        if element.respondsToSelector(aSelector) {
            element.performSelector(aSelector) // This doesn't work in Swift
        }
    }

    return super.forwardingTargetForSelector(aSelector)
}
```

I'm aware of the Objective-C imports to enable a Swift variant for `performSelector`, but I'm looking for a purely Swift solution here.

Comment: Assuming that your elements are inherit from NSObject I don't think that you can achieve purely Swift solution since NSObject its not a Swift type. In my opinion the Swift pure solution  would not use selectors at all, but only protocols and protocol conformance methods or swift class inhertance

Comment: Good point, true that. The problem with protocols is you have to implement each method in a mediator class and forward these methods to the once responding. I don't want to implement each delegate method, but basically automate this proces.

Comment: Still you can get rid of objc protocols and mark your methods as optionals. Thats not pure swift but its closer to it. Till than we must  wait for future swift releases with more swift implementations